# Send email to assigned user Sugar CRM Rest API

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Normally assigned user gets email when created/updated a lead in Sugar CRM.
I am using the REST API to add/update leads in suite CRM.I need to send email to the assigned user.How can it be done?

```
$url = "http://{site_url}/service/v4_1/rest.php";
$username = "admin";
$password = "password";

function call($method, $parameters, $url)
{
    ob_start();
    $curl_request = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($parameters);

    $post = array(
         "method" => $method,
         "input_type" => "JSON",
         "response_type" => "JSON",
         "rest_data" => $jsonEncodedData
    );

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result = curl_exec($curl_request);
    curl_close($curl_request);

    $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
    $response = json_decode($result[1]);
    ob_end_flush();

    return $response;
}

$login_parameters = array(
     "user_auth" => array(
          "user_name" => $username,
          "password" => md5($password),
          "version" => "1"
     ),
     "application_name" => "RestTest",
     "name_value_list" => array(),
);

$login_result = call("login", $login_parameters, $url);


$session_id = $login_result->id;

$set_entry_parameters = array(
     "session" => $session_id,
     "module_name" => "Leads",


     "name_value_list" => array(

          array("firstnamename" => "name", "email1" => "email","assigned_user_id"=>"xxxxx-xxxxx-xx-x-xxx"),
     ),
);

$set_entry_result = call("set_entry", $set_entry_parameters, $url);


?>
```

I can update the record.I need to send the email to the assigned user id.

Comment: show us some code

Comment: updated the code.check it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a known bug in Sugar API since version 6.5 (and not yet corrected).

[Creating a new Lead via the API not sending email Version 6.5.16 (Build 1082)](http://Creating%20a%20new%20Lead%20via%20the%20API%20not%20sending%20email%20Version%206.5.16%20(Build%201082))

[Defect 68115: Cases created or updated and assigned via REST API doesn't send out a notification](https://web.sugarcrm.com/support/issues/2cd5f080-89d9-b479-292d-53359e45efe6)

In the original forum post a guy suggested using logic hooks as a workaround. I know logic hooks exist but never used them, though I believe it's a path to try.

Good luck!